# Samsung SPF-71N UPnP photo frame

Tags: upnp

I have a Samsung's photo frame which is connected to LAN. It broadcasts as UPnP device like that:

```
09:48:05.429956 IP 192.168.5.4.1900 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 279
E..3."@..............l.l...eNOTIFY * HTTP/1.1
LOCATION: http://192.168.5.4:57959/
HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
SERVER: POSIX, UPnP/1.0, Intel MicroStack/1.0.1868
NTS: ssdp:alive
USN: uuid:cc845bff-073b-c7de-1317-6c3e34888fd0
CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=1800
NT: uuid:cc845bff-073b-c7de-1317-6c3e34888fd0
```

Frame presents itself as urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaPlayer:1, but I cannot find this device type on UPnP Forum pages. Here is XML descriptor: https://www.dropbox.com/s/unuarev1ywr8hc5/ramka.xml

I tried to set up frame entering my DLNA server IP address (frame configuration), but didn't work. Frame says that there is no server it can play content from.
There is no MediaRenderer service so I cannot just send pictures. I suspect that frame is a "kind of client" but I don't know how to use it. User manual says nothing about media server and serving content from network.

Has anybody some idea how to figure it out?

Comment: hey, you find something usefull? I just bought this frame and trying display any media from local media server

Comment: No. I've just abandoned it as requires a lot time for research.

Answer (score 1):

The device type is MediaPlayer which suggests that it can discover your UPnP MediaServer using SSDP, and then you should be able to browse your photos and play them via the Samsung Photo Frame. Try switching your MediaServer off and then on to encourage it to send a NOTIFY packet so that the Photo Frame finds it.

The MediaPlayer device will not be recognised by standard UPnP CP apps (they are looking for MediaRenderer and MediaServer device types).

The device description XML lists AVTransport and Rendering control services which suggest that the Photo Frame can be controlled remotely e.g. play a photo, set brightness.

The non-standard UPnP device type and extra services suggest that there must be an App from Samsung for the Photo Frame. That is your best option for a remote control.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no MediaRenderer service so I cannot just send pictures

That's not the whole story. It's true that the device does not seem to implement ConnectionManager service so it couldn't be a compliant MediaRenderer device (and naming apparently proprietary Samsung things in the "upnp-org" namespace seems obnoxious to me), *but* the device does claim to implement RenderingControl and AVTransport so it's conceivable that it could be controlled with a (almost) standard control point...

As an example, I'm guessing gupnp-av-cp (a testing AV control point from gupnp-tools on most linux OSes) might work with a oneline change to replace the device type and another to set a fake renderer protocolinfo (basically making a guess on what kind of data the renderer accepts).

Comment: gupnp-av-cp doesn't show "MediaPlayer" (my frame) because it's not MediaServer nor MediaRenderer :/ gupnp-universal-cp allows me to call services but almost every getter service returns "Sample string" or "http://intel.com". Almost none of setter services works (need proper instanceID I think).

Comment: I did not say it would just work, I said it might work (as a renderer) _after_ some changes in gupnp-av-cp. This is a QA site for programming so I figured that would be relevant.